# Are dashes allowed in javascript property names?

Tags: javascript

I was looking at http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Defaults_and_Options to create a simple plugin for jQuery. Following the section about options and settings, I did the following, which didn't work (the script quit when it encountered the setting).

```
var settings = {
    'location' : 'top',
    'background-color': 'blue'
}
...
$this.css('backgroundColor', settings.background-color); // fails here
```

Once I removed the dash from the background color, things work properly.

```
var settings = {
    'location' : 'top',
    'backgroundColor': 'blue' // dash removed here
}
...
$this.css('backgroundColor', settings.backgroundColor);
```

Am I missing something, or are the jQuery docs wrong?

Comment: Note you are attempting to use `background-color` as a property accessor, not as a variable. Variables can only be Identifiers, property accessor are less strict and can be IdentifierNames (ReservedWords are not excluded). But in this case, `background-color` is neither Identifier nor IdentifierName.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

no. the parser will interpret it as the subtract operator.

you can do `settings['background-color']`.

Comment: I see. Thanks, this is what I should have used. $this.css('backgroundColor', options['background-color']);

Comment: Have to accept this answer because it's right, and includes such witty banter in the comments.

Comment: Much appreciated for this @dan!

Comment: @Daniel , Why we need to use [ ] bracket for Acess it ?

Comment: @VjyV because the javascript engine will interpret it as the `-` operator and not part of the property name.

Comment: Thus, the answer is actually "yes"... dashes *are* allowed in property names, as demonstrated above. They must be accessed using the above demonstrated fashion because otherwise they will be interpreted as the subtraction operator.

Comment: ^ You can access the property using the [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#dot_notation) when the property is a valid [JavaScript identifier](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Identifier) invalid identifiers can still be used as property, but must be accessed through the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#bracket_notation).

Answer (score 18):

Change `settings.background-color` to `settings['background-color']`.

Variables cannot contain `-` because that is read as the subtract operator.

Comment: This is important when decoding request headers and variables such as "content-type". I'm using the request module and I need to know the content type. I can use response.headers['content-type']

Answer (score 7):

You can do something like this:

```js
var myObject = {
  propertyOne: 'Something',
  'property-two': 'Something two'  
}

for (const val of [
  myObject.propertyOne,
  myObject['propertyOne'],
  myObject['property-two']
  ]){
  console.log(val)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Dashes are not legal in javascript variables.  A variable name must start with a letter, dollar sign or underscore and can be followed by the same or a number.

Comment: But this is not a variable.

Answer (score 5):

You can have dashes in strings. If you really wanted to keep that dash, you'd have to refer to the property using brackets and whatnot:

```
$this.css('backgroundColor', settings['background-color']);
```