# mongodb mapReduce returns NaN because of minus character

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, nan

My aim is to create a map function like this

```
map = function () { var key = {key:this.name-1}; emit(key, {count:1}); }
```

I pass the parameter "name-1" in a java code. But mongo takes it as "name minus 1". So key becomes and integer and so during map reduce I get NaN problem.

The map actually looks like this

```
map = function () { var key = {key:this.name - 1}; emit(key, {count:1}); }
```

how to overcome this problem?

Comment: what is the purpose of -1 if it's not a substraction ?

Comment: Apparently, that's a key name.

Comment: Dashes is not allowed in variable names at javascript variables, see [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516106/are-dashes-allowed-in-javascript-variable-names). It seems that easiest way fix error,it just rename property name to be without dash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phew finally this works.

```
map = function () { var key = {key:this["name-1"]}; emit(key, {count:1}); }
```