# Add CSS z-index property to css variable in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add css property to my css variable in Jquery.

```
var cssProp = {
    'position': 'absolute',
    'top': topPos,
    'left': leftPos
}

//this codes works
cssProp.top += 10;

//this is not..
cssProp.z - index = 10;
```

How to fix this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried `cssProp.zIndex=10;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dashes in properties when using dot notation are not allowed

```
cssProp['z-index'] = 10;
```

Note that css properties when talking about `element.style` all dashed elements in CSS are camel cased in JavaScript so it would propbably actually be `cssProp.zIndex = 10;`

Answer (score 0):

Possibly because z-index is not defined in cssProp

Try

```
var cssProp = {'position':'absolute',
                 'top': topPos,
                 'left': leftPos,
                 'z-index': 0
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing it the way you are you are creating a new variable called "z-index", which is invalid in javascript, and therefore not working.

Try calling it "zIndex" instead, that is a valid javascript variable name.

Answer (score 0):

Using `-` (dash) as a variable name/object key is not valid in javascript. Try using camelCase notation as zIndex.

**Read more:**

[Are dashes allowed in javascript variable names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516106/are-dashes-allowed-in-javascript-variable-names)

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
var cssProp = {
    'position':'absolute',
    'top': topPos,
    'left': leftPos,
    'zIndex': '0'
};
```

jQuery always removes the '-' and then concatenates the word using the camelcase style type.  I believe jQuery then has a regular expression that accomplishes this...