# jQuery attr() method to create a data dash attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attr

I'm trying to figure out why when adding a data-attribute to (Let's say an image) requires the attribute name to be put into quotes. I know that it needs to be done, but if a student asked me I wouldn't have the exact answer why. So take the two examples below.

1.) I'm looking for an explanation why the dash is a problem.
2.) Is there a way to escape it so you don't need to put it in quotes?

**This Doesn't work:**

```
$("img").attr({
    alt: "a picture of my cat",
    data-item : "pet",
    data-color : "orange",
});
```

**This Does work**

```
$("img").attr({
    alt: "a picture of my cat",
    'data-item' : "pet",
    'data-color' : "orange",
});
```

3.) The arguments that are passed to the attr() method is an object literal right?
4.) Is this just a rule in object literal syntax that a dash is not allowed?

Comment: If I can answer with another question: can you declare a variable named `data-color`? No, why?

Comment: `-` is not a dash, it's the minus operator

Comment: The parser will interpret it as the subtract operator.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516106/are-dashes-allowed-in-javascript-variable-names

Comment: You dont have `,` after "pet" @EricB

Comment: Thanks Thomas, your comment gave me the idea of what to search for to find the answer.

Comment: @Adriano, I'm writing a tutorial for jQuery and I'm going to use your posed question in my explanation and then state why. So even though I was a little unhappy with your comment at first. It makes you take a second and think as to why this is happening, I appreciate the comment. .. .. after thinking aboutit, lol

Comment: @EricB sorry!!! I'm not native speaker so (too) often I can't really catch the "tone" of a sentence. Yes, intent was to _hint_ (I appreciate it for myself when learning something), not to criticize. :)

Comment: No problem Adriano, like I said, it took me a few minutes to appreciate the comment, but it did make me think about it the way I should have approached this problem in the first place. The setting of that attribute name is bound by the same rules that setting a variable is bound by. And you can't use -dash for that reason.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1.) In object literals, the `-` symbol is not allowed as an identifier because it is also the minus operator in javascript.

2.) no, you have to use quotes.

3.) yes.

4.) yes, see 1.

Comment: for 3), jQuery says: "Note: Attribute values are strings with the exception of a few attributes such as value and tabindex."

Comment: @florin.prisecariu the attribute values are the actual values of the attributes, such `"as a picture of my cat"` in `alt`, not the things you pass to the `.attr` function

Comment: I appreciate that you answered the question in this format!

Answer (score 6):

I agree with [@Ferdi265](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24950622/370103).

However one additional point I would make is to use `jQuery.data()`.

`jQuery.data()` doesn't actually update the DOM, it updates a javascript object referencing the element and stores the value there.

It's much better for performance as no DOM manipulation is required.

```
$("img").attr({
    alt: "a picture of my cat"
}).data({
    item: "pet",
    color: "orange"
});
```

Obviously this doesn't update your element's attributes, and therefore any future reference to these values will have to be done with `jQuery.data()`;

```
$("img").data("item");
```

If you're interested in understanding how this works under-the-hood I wrote an article on it a while back:

http://curtistimson.co.uk/jquery/understanding-jquery-data-storage/

Comment: I will use this as a way to segue into the data method in my tutorial.

Comment: BTW.. OFF TOPIC.. I like your tutorial on jQUery namespacing http://curtistimson.co.uk/jquery/namespacing-jquery-event-handlers/ and I followed you on twitte. Great website!!!

Comment: @EricB Thanks Eric, I appreciate the feedback and I'm glad it was of some use :)

Comment: You think you could help me out with another question? I have a piece of jQUery that I need to demonstrate chaining first and then refactoring a piece of code into a loop? I have the example in JavaScript but Can't figure it out in jQUery..I could send you an email if its ok?

Comment: This data jQuery Storage tutorial is great. I think I'm going to spend some time on your site. lol

Comment: @EricB I recommend adding your question to StackOverflow. That way you not only get my advice, but the advice of the rest of the community. Furthermore your question and the solution will help future developers :)

Answer (score -1):

this is how I worked around it:

```
.attr({ style: "font-size : 50px;background-color : powderblue;font-family:arial" })
```

as a specific example of how to specify multiple attributes in an element creation statement. This is after the above examples did not work.