# AngularJS - $parse.assign returns not a function error for the string which contain '-'

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created an angularjs variable parsing example and it works perfectly in my environment. Below highlighting the code of my implementation

```
var model = $parse("ABC_DEF");
model.assign($scope, chart); //Works successfully
```

But here i just changed the variable name to "ABC-DEF". Then  i implement the variable to the same code of above, but here it shows the exception like `assign is not a function in $parse`. Below showing the error throwing line of codes

```
var model = $parse("ABC-DEF");
model.assign($scope, chart); //Not Working- shows assign not a function
```

What is the reason of this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ABC-DEF` is not a valid variable name in Javascript as the dash is interpreted as the substract operator [(related question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516106/are-dashes-allowed-in-javascript-variable-names).

So if you look at the [expression guide - angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression):

> Angular expressions are JavaScript-like code snippets that are usually placed in bindings such as `{{ expression }}`.

Angular is interpreting this expression `"ABC-DEF"` as a binary function [(source)](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/fbad2805703569058a4a860747b0e2d8aee36bdf/src/ng/parse.js#L449), not an assignable expression.

Answer (score 0):

You may use *double quote* on that..

example:

```
$parse("sample['ABC-DEF']").assign($scope, sample);
```