# How to handle if the data param contains -(hiphen) symbol?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to send http request using ajax call(POST) & params along with setheaders. Params consist of a special character "-".
I'm facing following error :-

```
 callCount:"1",
 page:"/portalcareer?_s.crb=kyJ6d%252fC9jtNjs4BrI7xhqEHgCfU%253d",
 scriptSessionId:"80A8BD291A8E635A37D57F13E5D1F423898",
 c0-scriptName:"picklistControllerProxy",
 c0-methodName:"getChildPickLists",
 c0-id:"0",
 c0-param0:"string:%7B0%20%3A%20341%7D",
 c0-param1:"string:school",
 batchId:"11"
```

I'm getting error at

> c0-scriptName:"picklistControllerProxy",

[image: Error at - charcter]

[image: Clicked on that and verified its happening exactly there only]

This is my Code

```
  $("#typeOfSchool").change(function () {
         jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                beforeSend: function (abc)
                {
                   abc.setRequestHeader("X-Ajax-Token","ASfafqXVKiGWRh9fBWaJ4XlYI%2fY%3d");
                   abc.setRequestHeader("Accept", "*/*");
                   abc.setRequestHeader("Accept-Encoding","gzip, deflate");
                   abc.setRequestHeader("Accept-Language","en-US,en;q=0.8");
                   abc.setRequestHeader("Connection","keep-alive");
                   abc.setRequestHeader("Content-Length","292");
                   abc.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","text/plain");
                   abc.setRequestHeader("Host","career4.successfactors.com");
                   abc.setRequestHeader("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36");
                },
                 data: {
                    callCount:"1",
                    page:"/portalcareer?_s.crb=kyJ6d%252fC9jtNjs4BrI7xhqEHgCfU%253d",
                    scriptSessionId:"80A8BD291A8E635A37D57F13E5D1F423898",
                    c0-scriptName:"picklistControllerProxy",
                    c0-methodName:"getChildPickLists",
                    c0-id:"0",
                    c0-param0:"string:%7B0%20%3A%20341%7D",
                    c0-param1:"string:school",
                    batchId:"11"
                },
                 url: 'https://careermela.xyz.com/xi/ajax/remoting/call/plaincall/picklistControllerProxy.getChildPickLists.dwr',
                 success: function(data){
                    alert("process success");
                    alert(data);
                 console.log('succes: '+data);
                  }
               });
    });
```

Comment: `I'm getting error at`. What kind of error do you get?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516106/are-dashes-allowed-in-javascript-variable-names This may help

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Can you please check the Screen shots.

Comment: Of course `-` is unexpected token for identifier in Javascript.

Comment: How to resolve it. Can you help me in that.

Comment: @EdwinKrause unable to understand the link you specified.

Comment: Change the property name to `c0ScriptName` for instance. Or create querystring and pass data as string instead of  object.

Comment: Basically means to wrap the names with hyphen into quotes, see answer below

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Can you please explain it clearly. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks all. Issue is solved by wrapping the quotes.

Comment: The New Issue is "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add quotes to your data

```
data: {
    "callCount":"1",
    "page":"/portalcareer?_s.crb=kyJ6d%252fC9jtNjs4BrI7xhqEHgCfU%253d",
    "scriptSessionId":"80A8BD291A8E635A37D57F13E5D1F423898",
    "c0-scriptName":"picklistControllerProxy",
    "c0-methodName":"getChildPickLists",
    "c0-id":"0",
    "c0-param0":"string:%7B0%20%3A%20341%7D",
    "c0-param1":"string:school",
    "batchId":"11"
}
```

if that doesn't work add content type to your ajax call and stringify your data.

```
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'

var data = {
                "callCount":"1",
                "page":"/portalcareer?_s.crb=kyJ6d%252fC9jtNjs4BrI7xhqEHgCfU%253d",
                "scriptSessionId":"80A8BD291A8E635A37D57F13E5D1F423898",
                "c0-scriptName":"picklistControllerProxy",
                "c0-methodName":"getChildPickLists",
                "c0-id":"0",
                "c0-param0":"string:%7B0%20%3A%20341%7D",
                "c0-param1":"string:school",
                "batchId":"11"
            }

jQuery.ajax({
          ...
          data: JSON.stringify(data),
          ...
});
```

Comment: For me it works fine, take a look here http://jsfiddle.net/s4oufbrk/, change the code so i can reproduce your error

Comment: Yeah. I'll do there. Thanks.

Comment: This is basically how your code should look like http://jsfiddle.net/qczk26tt/2/, if you look in the net tab and expand the call to test.com you can see in the calls post tab that all of your parameters are there

Comment: Thanks, The Issue is solved, But got a new Issue now "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Comment: This usually happens when you make a Cross Origin request. If you are calling site A from site B you need to add header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://siteB.com"); to the header of the resource from site B

Comment: looking into what you said. Thanks.

Comment: Still it is not working. XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://career4.successfactors.com/xi/ajax/remoting/call/plaincall/picklistControllerProxy.getChildPickLists.dwr. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://weltman-local:8080' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

Comment: What did you add? Because you are on localhost you try adding  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * this will allow access to career4.successfactors.com for any website, if you do not have access to career4.successfactors.com there is nothing you can do

Comment: Yes. That is correct But I can execute this through rest client perfectly. So, I conclude that I have written some wrong code.