# What's wrong in the code below?

Tags: javascript, ajax, syntax

I get a console error: 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token -'
What's wrong? Please, may anyone help?

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#widget_settings_holder").find(".tbLanguageTabs").first().tabs();

      var cmpt-br = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("text_widget_text_pt-br"), {
      mode:        "htmlmixed",
      lineNumbers: true,
      tabMode:     "indent"
    });

    $(tbApp).off("tbWidget:onUpdate.textWidget").one("tbWidget:onUpdate.textWidget", function(event, $widget, $form) {

      if ($widget.attr("id").split("_")[1] != "HtmlWidget") {
          return;
      }

          cmpt-br.toTextArea();
          $form.find("textarea[name$='[text]']").each(function() {
        $(this).val(utf8_to_b64($(this).val()));
      });
    });

  });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are dashes allowed in javascript variable names?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5516106/1529630)

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>  var cmpt-br =
> ```

`-` is a [subtraction operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.2). You can't use it in a variable name.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript doesn't allow dashes in the name of variables.

So your line

```
var cmpt-br = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("text_widget_text_pt-br"), {
```

Is incorrect because of the name of your variable. You can use underscore for your purpose.

```
var cmpt_br = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("text_widget_text_pt-br"), {
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var cmpt-br =
```

Use an underscore, not a hyphen. JavaScript evaluates it as an expression.