# How to select id and class in select options at same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have implemented jquery chosen in my [blog](http://blogupdatesmyme.blogspot.in/) The problem is i have changed the code `<select id="cmbColumn" name="cmbColumn">`  to
 `<select class="chosen-select" name="chosen-select">`

I have assign the class because to achieve like below

```
<script>
  $(function(){
    $(".chosen-select").chosen(); 
});
</script>
```

But the problem is the value is not filtering because the class is not taking by ID `document.getElementById("chosen-select").value;`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getValue() {
     var valchosen-select = document.getElementById("chosen-select").value;
     var valcmbSidebar = document.getElementById("cmbSidebar").value;

    valOutput = "label:"+valchosen-select+"|label:"+ valcmbSidebar;
    window.open("/search/?q=" + valOutput, "_self");
  }
</script>
```

Can i give id and class to the same select option like the below `<select class="chosen-select" id="chosen-select" name="chosen-select">`  Does it works or any other solution.

Comment: Solution for what? It's not at all clear what the problem is or what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Don't use hyphens for js variables. It is treated as minus. After that you will be OK

Comment: actually i need to get the values filter so i want to use id for the class also i mean same id and same class

Comment: Use the plugin api to get your values. No reason you have to use ID or class that has `chosen` in it just to use plugin either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `.chosen()` is not a standard jQuery method, it's from a **[plugin](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)**.
2. There's 2 `<script>` tags for the plugin. One of them doesn't work, see *fig1.*.
3. `<option>` tags should be closed, see *fig2.*.
4. As Mr. Gel Boy has already stated: avoid **[hyphenating variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5516115/2813224)**. The hyphen <kbd>-</kbd> will be confused for a minus <kbd>-</kbd>.
5. As Mr.(Ms.?) charlietfl has already stated: id is not needed when using the **[Chosen API](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)**, see *fig3.*.

#### fig1.

```
<script src="//harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<link href="//harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
```

Notice the 2 `<script>` blocks on the top and bottom. The plugin needs jQuery loaded before it can function. Also, in this instance (and in most common instances), you don't need to load 2 of the same script. Remove the top one.

#### Fig2.

```
WRONG: <option value="apple"/>Apple
CORRECT: <option value="apple">Apple</option>
```

#### Fig3.

```
$('.chosen-select').chosen();
```

This is correct, ***BUT*** in your circumstances it would be better if you use [camelCas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase)e like so:

```
$('.chosenSelect').chosen();
```

The following Snippet shows a single and a multiple select using the chosen plugin. I'm assuming your problem is that you are not aware or do not know how to use the plugin, or it's because of the hyphenated variable, so in short:

> Set the class of your selects to an arbitrary name without any <kbd>-</kbd>, and invoke the plugin targeting that class name. Keep your variables simple without <kbd>-</kbd>. The plugin will handle the events and will allow you to do other things that would take a lot of work and coding to do.

#### SNIPPET

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Chosen Plugin</title>
  <link href="https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    fieldset {
      max-width: 300px;
      font-family: 'Verdana';
    }
    fieldset * {
      font-family: inherit;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Chosen Plugin</legend>

    <b><label for="sel1">Single Select</label></b>
    <select id="sel1" class="chosenSelect" name="sel1" data-placeholder="Columns">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="apple+">Apple</option>
      <option value="berries+">Berries</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <b><label for="sel2">Multiple Select</label></b>
    <select id="sel2" class="chosenSelect" name="sel2" data-placeholder="Sidebars" multiple>
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="grapes+">Grapes</option>
      <option value="mango+">Mango</option>
      <option value="pear+">Pear</option>
      <option value="cherries+">Cherries</option>
    </select>

    <input onclick="getValue()" value="Filter" type="button">
  </fieldset>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
  <script>
    function getValue() {
      var valchosenSelect = document.getElementById("sel1").value;
      var valcmbSidebar = document.getElementById("sel2").value;

      valOutput = "label:" + valchosenSelect + "|label:" + valcmbSidebar;
      window.open("https://blogupdatesmyme.blogspot.in/search/?q=" + valOutput, "_self");
    }

    $(function() {
      $(".chosenSelect").chosen({
        width: "95%"
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html
```

Comment: sorry for late reply your help appriecable

Comment: No problem, I'm happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

You can have the same class name as an ID, but I wouldn't recommend it - an ID has to be unique in your code, and a class name doesn't have to be.

If you removed the id attribute, you can't use getElementById and query the DOM for it.
Instead, use getElementsByClassName - notice this returns a collection, so assuming you only have one element with this class name, you will need to use `getElementsByClassName("chosen-select")[0].value`.

Comment: getElementsByClassName("chosen-select")[0].value what is 0 in that i wont understand can u explain

Comment: Value needs to come from plugin api

Comment: @charlietfl how can i use getElementsByClassName in this code <script type="text/javascript">
function getValue() {
     var valchosen-select = document.getElementById("chosen-select").value;
     var valcmbSidebar = document.getElementById("cmbSidebar").value;

    valOutput = "label:"+valchosen-select+"|label:"+ valcmbSidebar;
    window.open("/search/?q=" + valOutput, "_self");
  }
</script> should i use classname where ever the id is used or what...?

Comment: @vijaykumar [0] is the first element in the collection you get for using getElementsByClassName. If you use an ID, you can use getElementById and you will only get the one element (and not a collection with one element).