# Form values not binding and presenting a blank variable

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

Some of the ng bindings are displaying as blank within the object. Some of my inputs require ngStandAlone and the form uses a star rating custom component. The form inputs are defined individually in the object as blank strings, but the text areas aren't binding to these definitions as they show 'NaN' in the emulator.

**[Fixed: Cannot use dashes in ng bindings - replaced with underscores to fix issue]**

**In the component:**

```
remark: any;

constructor() {

      this.remark = {
                'problem': '',
                'problem-comments': '',
                'easy-to-use': '',
                'information-good': '',
                'recommend-app': '',
                'improvement-comments': '',
                'name': '',
                'email': ''
            };
}
```

**In the template (html):**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">
    <ion-label>Please select one</ion-label>
    <ion-list radio-group [(ngModel)]="remark.problem" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label class="small-text">Scenic location was not correct</ion-label>
            <ion-radio value="scenic"></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label class="small-text">The shopping was not a good experience as service was poor</ion-label>
            <ion-radio value="shopping"></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label class="small-text">Food quality was poor</ion-label>
            <ion-radio value="food"></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item>
            <ion-label stacked>Problem Comments</ion-label>
            <ion-textarea [(ngModel)]="remark.problem-comments" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" placeholder="Write your comment here"></ion-textarea>
        </ion-item>

    </ion-list>

    <ion-label>Please rate to help us improve Application.</ion-label>

    <ion-label class="small-text">Was easy to use</ion-label>
    <rating [(ngModel)]="remark.easy-to-use" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"></rating>

    <ion-label class="small-text">Information on opening was good</ion-label>
    <rating [(ngModel)]="remark.information-good" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"></rating>

    <ion-label class="small-text">Recommend Application to other people</ion-label>
    <rating [(ngModel)]="remark.recommend-app" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"></rating>

    <ion-label class="small-text">Improvement Comments</ion-label>
    <ion-textarea [(ngModel)]="remark.improvement-comments" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" placeholder="Write your comment here"></ion-textarea>

    <hr>

    <ion-item>
        <ion-label stacked>Your Name</ion-label>
        <ion-input [(ngModel)]="remark.name" name="name"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label stacked>Your Email</ion-label>
        <ion-input [(ngModel)]="remark.email" name="email"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <button ion-button type="submit" block>Send</button>
</form>
```

**Console response after submission:**

```
Object

    easy-to-use: ""

    email: "Joshn@hotmail.com.au"

    improvement-comments: ""

    information-good: ""

    name: "Josh"

    problem: "scenic"

    problem-comments: ""

    recommend-app: ""
```

Text area's aren't binding and stars (possibly a problem related to the individual component)

Comment: try using underscore instead of dash.. that is the problem.. or try `obj['property']` in ngModel

Comment: @suraj thankyou, replacing with underscore fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.remark = [];`

you are defining an array in the component. In your template, you are accessing as object and its property:

```
<ion-list radio-group [(ngModel)]="remark.problem" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
```

Declare the class variable as:

```
remark:{problem:string};
```

And in the constructor,

```
  this.remark = {
    problem:''
  }
```

> I also have a text area `<ion-textarea [(ngModel)]="remark.improvement-comments" > [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" placeholder="Write your comment here">>
>    </ion-textarea>` not showing in the array

It is not an array. it is an object. just add the property which you need to like improvement-comments in declaration and constructor definition like so:

```
remark:{
   problem:string,
   'improvement_comments':string
   };
```

In the constructor,

```
  this.remark={
   problem:'',
  'improvement_comments':''
   };
```

**Note**: I suggest you use underscore instead of dash because [dashes in variable names in javascript can cause errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516106/are-dashes-allowed-in-javascript-variable-names)

It is taken as a subtraction operator by js.

Comment: Thanks suraj. I also have a text area `<ion-textarea [(ngModel)]="remark.improvement-comments" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" placeholder="Write your comment here"></ion-textarea>` not showing in the array

Comment: its _not an array_.. it is an object.. just add the property which you need to like `improvement-comments` in declaration and constructor definition