# margin-left for DOM element is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried to create a dynamic P element with the margin-left as 33px.But it is not working. But the same is working fine when the left is not used(margin) and with static html p element. Why is it so? I've tried with the IE11 and Chrome Version 60.0.3112.113.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Chat</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="screenv" style="border:1px solid black;margin: 5px;padding: 5px;width: 300px;height: 300px;"></div></br>
    <input id="tb" type="text" style="border:1px solid black;margin: 5px;padding: 5px;width: 300px;" placeholder="Enter your text"></input>
    <button onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
    <p style="margin-left:33px;">hello</p>//css works fine
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var you="",screen="",msg="",c_time="",val="",d,h,m,line;
        function submit() {

        val=document.getElementById("tb").value;
        screen=document.getElementById('screenv');

        you=document.createElement("div");
        you.innerHTML="You:";

        screen.appendChild(you);


        c_time=document.createElement("p");
        d = new Date();
        h = d.getHours();
        m = d.getMinutes();
        c_time.innerHTML = h+":"+m;
        c_time.style.display="inline";
        c_time.style.color="grey";

        msg=document.createElement("p");
        msg.innerHTML=val;
        msg.style.margin-left="33px";//not working


        line=document.createElement("br");

        you.appendChild(c_time);
        you.appendChild(line);
        you.appendChild(msg);
        document.getElementById("tb").value="";
    }


    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Change `margin-left` to `marginLeft`.

Comment: _“Why is it so?”_ - because as everyone who bothered to learn the basics of the syntax knows, `-` is the subtraction operator ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`msg.style.margin-left="33px";` will be interpreted [as subtract operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516106/are-dashes-allowed-in-javascript-variable-names) by the Parser. Thus, all CSS properties with dashes are written in [camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) within Javascript.