# $setValidity function is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have following code block in my Angular JS app. (this is a simplified version of huge code)

**HTML**

```
<form name="form-demo">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="modeldemo.date" ng-change="functiondemo1();"/>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="modeldemo.date" ng-change="functiondemo2();"/>
    <select class="form-control" name="move" ng-model="modeldemo.move" ng-options="move.type for move in moveList" ng-required="true">
    </select>
</form>
```

**JS file**

```
app.controller('moveCtrl', function($scope, $http, NgTableParams, $filter, $timeout) {
    $scope.moveList = {};

    $scope.functiondemo2 = function() {
        // get the data from server and assign to $scope.moveList
    }

    $scope.functiondemo1 = function() {
        $scope.modeldemo.move = null;
    }
}
```

Dropdown should be cleared when first input box value changed. Dropdown values should be loaded when second input changed.

But since `ng-required` attribute set as `true` in dropdown, when `functiondemo1` gets called, 'This field is required' error is shown.

So I have modified the `functiondemo1` as follows.

```
$scope.functiondemo1 = function1() {
    $scope.modeldemo.move = null;
    $scope.form-demo.move.$setValidity("required", true);
}
```

Then I'm getting following error in console.

```
angular.js:12477 TypeError: Cannot read property '$setValidity' of undefined
    at b.$scope.functiondemo1 (http://localhost:8080/js/script.js:63:16)
    at fn (eval at compile (http://localhost:8080/angular/angular.min.js:212:409), <anonymous>:4:590)
    at b.$eval (http://localhost:8080/angular/angular.min.js:133:221)
    at pre (http://localhost:8080/angular/angular.min.js:257:49)
    at aa (http://localhost:8080/angular/angular.min.js:73:90)
    at K (http://localhost:8080/angular/angular.min.js:61:354)
    at g (http://localhost:8080/angular/angular.min.js:54:410)
    at g (http://localhost:8080/angular/angular.min.js:54:433)
    at g (http://localhost:8080/angular/angular.min.js:54:433)
```

I have also checked the following and nothing worked.

```
$scope.form-demo.move.$setPristine();
$scope.form-demo['move'].$setValidity("required", true);
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem may be caused by the dash character in your form name. Dashes aren't allowed in javascript variable names (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516106/are-dashes-allowed-in-javascript-property-names) ), so your line

```
$scope.form-demo.move.$setValidity("required", true);
```

probably gets interpreted as:

```
($scope.form) - (demo.move.$setValidity("required", true))
```

ence the error.

I have converted your sample to a Stack snippet and $setValidation call seems to work as expected, can you please check if you notice any other mayor difference with your actual code?

```js
var app = angular.module("demoApp", []);

app.controller('moveCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.moveList = [
      {type: "type1", id: 1},
      {type: "type2", id: 2},
      {type: "type3", id: 3}
    ];


    $scope.changeHandler = function () {
      $scope.modeldemo.move = null;
      
      $scope.formDemo.move.$setValidity("customRule", false);
    }
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="moveCtrl">
<form name="formDemo">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="modeldemo.date" ng-change="changeHandler();"/>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="modeldemo.date" ng-change="changeHandler();"/>
    <select class="form-control" name="move" ng-model="modeldemo.move" ng-options="move.type for move in moveList" ng-required="true">
    </select>
</form>

<p>The select's valid state is:</p>
<h1>{{formDemo.move.$valid}}</h1>
</div>
```