# Unable to get JSON Array name includes hyphen ( '-' (example: item.media-metadata[0].url )

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

In React native -  I don't know how to get json data value that's key name contains a hyphen(-) like media-metadata

this is the API json response

```
 "approved_for_syndication": 1,
                "media-metadata": [
                    {
                        "url": "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/05/13/business/00deutschetrump2/merlin_154640208_f27c634b-ab02-42af-8c94-10d4b01d8ddf-square320.jpg",
                        "format": "square320",
                        "height": 320,
                        "width": 320
                    },
                    {
                        "url": "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/05/13/business/00deutschetrump2/merlin_154640208_f27c634b-ab02-42af-8c94-10d4b01d8ddf-thumbStandard.jpg",
                        "format": "Standard Thumbnail",
                        "height": 75,
                        "width": 75
                    },
```

and this is the code I have tried

```
  <Image source = {
      {
        uri: item.media-metadata[0].url,
        isStatic: true
      }
    }
    style = {
      {
        width: 100,
        height: 100
      }
    }
    />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get JSON objects value if its name contains dots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577172/how-to-get-json-objects-value-if-its-name-contains-dots)

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869627/unable-to-access-json-property-with-dash , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8758715/using-number-as-index-json , ...

Comment: Try `item.['media-metadata'][0].url` ; '-' is being read as a special character here. Read this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516106/are-dashes-allowed-in-javascript-property-names

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to access JSON property with "-" dash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869627/unable-to-access-json-property-with-dash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
item["media-metadata"][0].url
```