# Why do I have to access my object property with the bracket annotation

Tags: javascript

So I have this object called items

[image]

And I want to access the columnOrder property

Why do I have to access it like this

```
 for (let item in items ) {
       console.log(items[item].columnOrder)
 }
```

and can't do

```
  for (let item in items ) {
      console.log(items.item.columnOrder)
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the `items` object ?

Comment: Yes I changed the screenshot of the items object to be more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is for accessing the value fo the dynamic object property we have to use bracket `[]` notation, as using dot notation will simply return `undefined` as shown below.

For example:

```js
var myCar = {
    make: 'Ford',
    model: 'Mustang',
    year: 1969
};

console.log( myCar['make'] )
console.log( myCar.make )
```

Here bracket `[]` notation is working as we are passing the object property as a string and also dot notation is working as we have passed exact object key `make` which exits on the object.

But if we store the key in a variable and try to use the bracket and dot notation, here is what happens:

```js
var myCar = {
    make: 'Ford',
    model: 'Mustang',
    year: 1969
};
var propertyName = 'make';

console.log( myCar[propertyName] )
console.log( myCar.propertyName )
```

You can see bracket notation worked as all keys in the square bracket notation are converted to string unless they're Symbols, since JavaScript object property names (keys) can only be strings or Symbols. Thus `myCar[propertyName]` is evaluated as `myCar['make']` which gives the correct result.

But with dot notation, it simply means that you are trying to access an unassigned property of `myCar` object, which will always return `undefined`.

In your case, as you are using:

```
items.item.columnOrder
```

This results in an error like:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'columnOrder' of undefined

as you are trying to access `columnOrder` from `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

Dashes are not allowed because it will get interpreted as the subtraction operator. Similar post: [Are dashes allowed in javascript property names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516106/are-dashes-allowed-in-javascript-property-names)