# Read data with dash operator using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

This seems to be very silly to me but I am having this problem. Can anybody help me with this.
So, I have an API that I am fetching some data and seems that the API response has a data format like this:

```
start-time:2323232
end-time:2332323
```

Now, when in my react rendering component, I am trying to display the data like this:

```
{data.start-time}
```

I am actually getting an error saying that time is undefined. Are there any rules that we cannot read/display data in JSX with - separator or something like that. Or, Does anybody know how can I solve that problem. Any helps would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `data["start-time"]`, you cannot use `start-time` as if it were an identifier, because it isn't.

Comment: in javascript you cant use dash in variable name.  So start-time will raise an error. to read the value associated with start-time from object, you should write ```data["start-time"]```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are dashes allowed in javascript property names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516106/are-dashes-allowed-in-javascript-property-names)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `start-time` as an identifier. you need to use square brackets to access the property in this case

`data["start-time"]`

For further reference [Object property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)

Answer (score 0):

You can only use the [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#dot_notation) if the property name is a valid JavaScript [identifier](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Identifier).

> In [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/JavaScript), identifiers are case-sensitive and can contain [Unicode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Unicode) letters, `$`, `_`, and digits (0-9), but may not start with a digit.

Properties that are not valid identifiers must be accessed through the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#bracket_notation).

```js
const data = { name: "stopwatch", "start-time": 2323232, "end-time": 2332323 };
console.log(data.name); // <- valid identifier
console.log(data["start-time"]); // <- invalid identifier
```