# ';' expected. | document.body.style.background-image = ``

Tags: javascript

Here is my code:
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzTsy.jpg)

```
 function toggle() {
     document.body.style.background-image = `
     linear-gradient(
      60deg,
      hsl(0deg 0% 0%) 0%,
      hsl(137deg 0% 1%) 0%,
      hsl(137deg 0% 2%) 0%,
      hsl(137deg 0% 4%) 2%,
      hsl(137deg 0% 5%) 5%,
      hsl(137deg 0% 5%) 10%,
      hsl(137deg 0% 6%) 19%,
      hsl(137deg 0% 6%) 42%,
      hsl(261deg 17% 14%) 88%,
      hsl(259deg 25% 27%) 97%,
      hsl(258deg 28% 40%) 100%,
      hsl(258deg 36% 54%) 100%
    );`;
  }
```

I am getting an error on line 43 saying

';' expected.

I dont know why and I doubt its an issue with the backticks. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are dashes allowed in javascript property names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516106/are-dashes-allowed-in-javascript-property-names)

Comment: I could do that. But is there a reason I'm getting the error above?

Comment: Yes. Since `-` is not allowed to be used in an identifier, your statement is read as `document.body.style.background - image` (`document.body.style.background` subtracted by the `image` variable), you can't place an `=` after that. A more understandable example would be `var1 - var2 = "some string";` which is not a valid statement. Use `document.body.style.backgroundImage` instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reference a JavaScript object property with a hyphen in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122609/how-do-i-reference-a-javascript-object-property-with-a-hyphen-in-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its backgroundImage, not background-image

```
function toggle() {
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = `
    linear-gradient(
      60deg,
      hsl(0deg 0% 0%) 0%,
      hsl(137deg 0% 1%) 0%,
      hsl(137deg 0% 2%) 0%,
      hsl(137deg 0% 4%) 2%,
      hsl(137deg 0% 5%) 5%,
      hsl(137deg 0% 5%) 10%,
      hsl(137deg 0% 6%) 19%,
      hsl(137deg 0% 6%) 42%,
      hsl(261deg 17% 14%) 88%,
      hsl(259deg 25% 27%) 97%,
      hsl(258deg 28% 40%) 100%,
      hsl(258deg 36% 54%) 100%
    )
    `;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

When we select any css double word property in JS like max-height, margin-left etc. we remove the '-' and capitalize the first letter of the second word like maxHeight or marginLeft. do So it will be backgroundImage.

```js
document.body.style.backgroundImage = `
    linear-gradient(
      60deg,
      hsl(0deg 0% 0%) 0%,
      hsl(137deg 0% 1%) 0%,
      hsl(137deg 0% 2%) 0%,
      hsl(137deg 0% 4%) 2%,
      hsl(137deg 0% 5%) 5%,
      hsl(137deg 0% 5%) 10%,
      hsl(137deg 0% 6%) 19%,
      hsl(137deg 0% 6%) 42%,
      hsl(261deg 17% 14%) 88%,
      hsl(259deg 25% 27%) 97%,
      hsl(258deg 28% 40%) 100%,
      hsl(258deg 36% 54%) 100%
    )
    `;
```

```css
h1{color:white}
```

```html
<h1>Body with Linead Gradient Background</h1>
```